# Webdriver selenium java partial xpath with contains- can't click element

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on an element using partial xpath. I can't use ID because there are more than one elements with the same ID. I know my xpath is correct because when I enter it in firepath it highlights the correct element.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="acme_color_swatches">
<div class="acme_color_swatch " data-color="#CC0000" style=" background-color:#CC0000"></div>
<div class="acme_color_swatch " data-color="#F9F9F9" style=" background-color:#F9F9F9"></div>
<div class="acme_color_swatch" data-color="#990000" style=" background-color:#990000"></div>
<div class="acme_color_swatch" data-color="#FAFAC5" style=" background-color:#FAFAC5"></div>
<div class="acme_color_swatch selected" data-color="#333333" style=" background-color:#333333"></div>
<div class="acme_color_swatch " data-color="#F2F2F2" style=" background-color:#F2F2F2"></div>
<div class="acme_color_swatch " data-color="#F7F7F7" style=" background-color:#F7F7F7"></div>
<div class="acme_color_swatch" data-color="#CB0000" style=" background-color:#CB0000"></div>
<div class="acme_color_swatch " data-color="#DDDDDD" style=" background-color:#DDDDDD"></div>
<div class="acme_color_swatch " data-color="#E2F2FF" style=" background-color:#E2F2FF"></div>
<div class="acme_color_swatch" data-color="#F5F5F5" style=" background-color:#F5F5F5"></div>
<div class="acme_color_swatch" data-color="#0069FF" style=" background-color:#0069FF"></div>
```

Here is my selenium code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@style, '#0069FF')]")).click();
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
FAILED: main
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(@style, '#0069FF')]"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: here's the HTML code:

Comment: Here is my HTML code:
<div class="acme_color_swatches">
<div class="acme_color_swatch " data-color="#CC0000" style=" background-color:#CC0000"></div>
<div class="acme_color_swatch " data-color="#F9F9F9" style=" background-color:#F9F9F9"></div>
<div class="acme_color_swatch" data-color="#990000" style=" background-color:#990000"></div>

Answer (score 0):

I find the cssSelector easier and more reliable and it will likely work for you in this case. You can try something like this:

```
By.cssSelector("div[style$='#0069FF']");
```

This will find any `div` that has a style-attribute that ends with `#0069FF`.

Comment: Kim, thanks for a quick reply. I tried the css and i get the following error: The given selector //div[contains(@style, '#0069FF')] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.

Comment: OK, yes you actually have to use the `"div[style$='#0069FF']"`inside the cssSelector and not the xpath expression.

Comment: do u mind showing me how? i am very new to selenium. thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use most of the code line you have. So the complete code would be: `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[style$='#0069FF']")).click();`

Comment: thanks Kim, still didn't work but thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. There is a good source for help with CSS Selectors at [sauce labs](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors). Hope that can help you solve this.

Comment: One potential danger with this method is that this will fail if the style changes and background-color is no longer last. You could use `style*='#0069FF'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-color='#0069FF']")).click();
```

It's looking for a DIV that has a `data-color` attribute = #0069FF.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but i still can't get it to work. I get "Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div[data-color='#0069FF']"}" error. Below is my partial xpath:

Comment: Can you share a link to the page? This should work given the HTML you provided.

Comment: //div[contains(@data-color, '##DDDDDD')]

Comment: and here is my css selector path

Comment: html body.site_page.lightthatch div#mainwrap div#bodyContainer.container-fluid div#bodywrap.row-fluid div#mainContainer.span24 div#campaignSetupContainer div.acme_dfm_outer div.acme_dfm_main.with_preview div.acme_dfm_main_content div div#acme_texture_selector.acme_texture_selector div.acme_dfm_image_area div.acme_texture_color_pallete div.acme_color_swatches div.acme_color_swatch.selected

Comment: Please put these additions into your question so others can see it and so that it can be formatted properly and more easily read. Thanks.

Comment: i am going to start a new clean thread and put everything in one place to make it easier for others to read.

Comment: You should just edit this question... or at least delete it after you create a new one so you don't leave this question orphaned and unanswered (and a duplicate of the new one).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by myself. Here is what I did:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@style, ' background-color:#FAFAC5')]")).click();
There is a space between the hyphen and the ' background-. This was causing all of the grief.

Answer (score 0):

These div are an array, so you can use:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='acme_color_swatch'])[11]")).click();`

to click on the 11th element which class **is acme_color_swatch**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use some logic here. Try to find the all webelements with `classname` and then find your specific color. Try the code below:

```
public void Findelement() throws InterruptedException {
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.classname("acme_color_swatch"));
    String Color = "#0069FF";
    if (element.contains(Color)){
        element.click();
    }
}
```